# MariaDB generated column vs. built-in function, which one is faster?

Tags: mariadb, query-optimization

Field `date` is YYYY-MM-DD by default.

Query 1:

```
select date_format(`date`,'%d-%m-%Y') from myTable;
```

Query 2:

```
select `genDate` from myTable;
```

Being `date_format(date,'%d-%m-%Y') as genDate`, is a virtual, non-indexed, generated column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a non-persistent, non-indexed column, those two queries are equivalent.

In other circumstances -- if the column was persistent and indexed -- then Query 2 would benefit from the index, skipping the main storage and reading the (most likely) smaller index, using an operation similar to Full Index Scan. That would make it faster.

But as a general rule, both queries are equivalent in terms of resources and performance.